# What is the probability that the needle crosses a line?

Tags: probability

Solve the following variant of the Buffon's needle problem: a needle of length $L>1$ is randomly thrown on a sheet of paper with horizontal lines on all integer points such that the vertical position $X$ (modulo $1$) is uniform on [$0,1$] and the angle $\theta$ is independent uniform on [$0,\pi$]. What is the probability that the needle crosses a line?

Comment: watch this video... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJVivjuMfWA

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a very similar if not identical question was asked very recently, but I can't find it. Has it been deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a fixed angle $\theta$, you should use geometry to determine the vertical extent of the needle, which (if less than 1) is the same as the probability that the needle crosses a line. (If that vertical extent is greater than 1, then the needle definitely crosses a line.) Then integrate the resulting expression over all $\theta$ between $0$ and $\pi$ and divide by $\pi$ (although, thanks to symmetry, $\theta\in[0,\pi/2]$ would be enough).